# Issues with subscripted variables in functions in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

new to mathematica and I have trouble when making subscripted functions in mathematica behave the way I want.

As an example:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["x", "1"]]];
Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["x", "2"]]];

Subscript[testfunc, Subscript[x, 1] : _, Subscript[x, 2] : _, j_] := 
  Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[x, j];
Subscript[testfunc, 10, 5, 1]
```

outputs:
50 Subscript[x, 1]

But, what I really wanted was for the function to set the values for x_1 and x_2 and output 500 (x_1^2*x_2). How do I do this?

Comment: Far far too many drink the "I MUST desktop publish my Mathematica input" Koolaid(tm). Nobody inside Wolfram has ever really admitted this, but I strongly suspect that Subscripts were glued on after many incompatible irreversible decisions had been made. The usual advice for using Subscripts in Mathematica is Nancy's Reagan's famous "Just say no." But since you must do this anyway start by reading this tutorial http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/585702   Then https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematica+subscript+problem

Comment: I would not use subscripted variables.